# CodeModuleManager.CMM_OK_MODULE_MARKED_FOR_DELETION on BlackBerry device

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

When I call `CodeModuleManager.deleteModuleEx()` to delete a Module, the return value is `CodeModuleManager.CMM_OK_MODULE_MARKED_FOR_DELETION` using the simulator, but the return value is `CodeModuleManager.CMM_OK` when I run same application on device. The device is a 9700 and the Platform is 5.1.0.121.

Answer (score 1):

i think after deletion reset is required. if you are not doing already,
add this code also.

```
 if (CodeModuleManager.isResetRequired())  
        CodeModuleManager.promptForResetIfRequired();
```

Comment: In my source, the two lines had already had after the delete is done.

Comment: In my source, the two lines had already added after the delete is done. The Dialog is used for confirm the return value. The return value = 0 on the device but it is 6 on simulator.